# Struggling to get the data from useDocument to display with vue.js and Firestore

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

I'm trying to get a single record from Firestore to display in Vue.js.  I'm using VueFire and the guide [here](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/guide/getting-started.html).

```html
<script setup>    
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore , doc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { useDocument } from 'vuefire'

const firebaseConfig = {...};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(firebaseApp);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

const place  = useDocument(doc(db, "data", "key"));
console.log(place)
</script>

<template>
  {{ place.title }}
</template>
```

The data logged is `RefImpl {__v_isShallow: false, dep: undefined, __v_isRef: true, _rawValue : {title: 'I am a title',` however when it gets to the template there is an error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Comment: this answers may be the solution you're after, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128557/any-easier-way-to-access-nested-object-properties-in-vue-template

Comment: Does this answer your question? [firebase - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72257173/firebase-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-opt)

Answer (score 3):

If anyone finds this because they need the data from `useDocument()` asynchronously, you can do something similar, based on Kyle's suggestion above (the Github post by the vueFire author):

```
const { data: place, promise } = useDocument(doc(db, 'data', 'key'))
promise.value.then((place) => {
  // do something with place like console.table(place)
})
```

Even if you don't want to listen for changes, you still have to use the "subscription" method to get the data asynchronously.  `async/await` doesn't work.  This needs to be a lot clearer in the documentation IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this.

```
...
const { data: place, pending } = useDocument(doc(db, "data", "key"));
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Place</h1>
  <template v-if="!pending">{{ place.title }}</template>
</template>
```

I'm just following what they the author of VueFire has posted here: https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/blob/df3c235f226d4e4c821391bcce74a1c3a6134406/packages/nuxt/playground/pages/firestore-useDocument.vue

You can use the `pending` property to show the place once it has loaded.

You can also read about Subscription State here where they talk about destructuring. https://v3.vuefire.vuejs.org/guide/realtime-data.html#subscription-state